# run a php page once a day using NAS synology

Tags: php, mysql, nas, synology

have a php page called cronEmail in the web folder. It incudes the code to end an email to specific users on the website. I want it to open the page once a day and send the email. The page has only php and MySql code to read the recipients of the email.

I am trying to use Task scheduler in the control panel to run the page. I create a user defined script and in schedule I set the time to a certain time and to only run daily once a day.

In the rum command i have tried numerous ways to run it on the time but every time it just passes and does nothing. an example of what I put in for the script is

```
/web/cronEmail.php OR
chmod 755 /volume1/web/cronEmail.php
```

There are only two of a many can anyone point me in the right direction
Thanks a million

Comment: Is PHP even installed on that system?

Comment: i have the .php pages saved in the web folder and when put in the ip xxx.xxx.x.xxx on the network it opens the index page which is the log in for  the website. I have the phpMyAdmin installed to store the database. Is there somthing I should install for PHP? we are new to this and still exploring. Thanks for the reply

Comment: You really haven't given a lot of context here. Does that script run via command-line without the scheduler? Why is the IP address relevant here?

Comment: i just have in task scheduler and in the user-defined script i have the path to the .php file. am I doing it wrong or what should I do?

Comment: I'm a little confused here as to how this is relevant to a NAS device, or what a NAS device is doing with PHP installed on it. Isn't that supposed to be for storage and not general purpose server-type duty?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a cronjob, in the terminal open cron with:

```
crontab -e
```

then at the bottom of the file place this

```
0 4 * * * php /url/to/folder/cronEmail.php
```

Comment: is all that in the user-defined script? sorry im new to this and its frying my brain

Comment: you will have to access the server via the command line and use them commands, but it will call your file once a day at 4am if you set the crontab

Comment: you can SSH into the server and you would interact with it on the command line, then you would configure the crontab

Comment: Although ssh solution is preferable, plus I would like that script outside the document root altogether if that is possible. However for cases like this when you have no shell access, you should consider a service like https://www.setcronjob.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found another solution, but this is what worked for me. If you put the following in the "Run Command" section, it should work:

```
php /volume1/web/cronEmail.php
```

You can also create an error log by doing the following:

```
php /volume1/web/cronEmail.php>> /volume1/web/errors.log 2>&1
```

If you don't use the `php` at the beginning, and open up the `error.log` file that is created, what you'll see is that the Task Scheduler doesn't seem to know that it's looking for PHP, and doesn't recognize the script.